# Robotic Arm Singularity Problem using velocity control

Tags: ros, moveit, servo

currently I am using Cartesian coordinate to move the end effector to a given point following aruco marker. I would like to know will there be any benefits using twist velocities command instead ? I am facing a lot of jumps and singularity issues, using tracking aruco markers coordinate. My main concern is low latency and smooth motion without jerks.

Comment: Could you give some more details about your problem? Maybe a video of the setup while an undesired behavior (say one _jump_) occurs, or a repo from which your case can be reproduced.